# Segmentation fault with System V shared memory

Tags: c, shared-memory, strcpy

I am trying to understand why this simple code leads to a segmentation fault when I try to copy some characters into shared memory using `strcpy`:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/sem.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    key_t key;
    int flag,id;
    char *buf;

    flag=IPC_CREAT|0600;
    if((key=ftok("myfile",12)) == -1 ) {
        perror("key");
        exit(2);
    }   
    printf("%X\n",key);

    if( (id=shmget(key,512,flag)) < 0) exit(1); 

    if( (buf=shmat(id,0,0)) < 0) exit(2);

    printf("PID %d, buf=%p\n",getpid(),buf);
    system("ipcs -m | grep 512");
    sleep(20);

    strcpy(buf,"Hello");
    sleep(100); 
    shmdt(buf);
    exit(0);
}
```

And here is what I get:

```
C1A0DAB
PID 12063, buf=0xffffffff8bc78000
0x0c1a0dab 271941746  username      600        512        1
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Moreover pmap of the process indicates :

```
00007f778bc78000      4K rw-s-    [ shmid=0x10358072 ]
```

I guess something's wrong with pointer `buf` but I don't know how to correct this so far.

Any ideas?

Comment: for shared memory, the code needs: #include <sys/types.h> and 
#include <sys/shm.h>

Comment: this: '#include <sys/ipc.h>' is for inter process communication, not shared memory. this: '#include <sys/sem.h>' is for semaphores, not shared memory

Comment: without the proper #include statements, this code causes the compiler to raise 17 warnings.  (and warnings need to be corrected)  BTW: when linking, are the correct libraries being accessed?

Comment: need #include <stdio.h>  for printf() etc.  need #include <unistd.h> for getpid() and sleep()

Comment: one of the files (sys/shm.h??) includes sys/ipc.h and compiling using that header file needs to have the following statement placed before the #include:  '#define _XOPEN_SOURCE' or '#define _SVID_SOURCE'

Comment: this line: 'if( (buf=shmat(id,0,0)) < 0) exit(2);' is comparing a pointer to an integer and a pointer cannot be less than 0  however, the  code could use: 'if( (buf=shmat(id,0,0)) == (void*)-1) exit(2);'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please compile with all warnings enabled (at least `-Wall` for gcc and clang for instance).

You're missing `#include <sys/shm.h>`, so your compiler assumes that `smhat` returns an int, when it in fact returns a `void*`. If the size of int and `void*` don't match, you have a problem.

Add that include, add the other ones you're missing too while you're at it, and it should work.

Comment: Thanks a lot, indeed #include <sys/shm.h> was missing.

Answer (score 1):

Pay attention to the warnings you get from the compiler.  In particular, you get:

```
file.c:22:5: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘shmat’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
file.c:22:13: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast
```

which tells you what the problem is -- the compiler is assuming that `shmat` returns a (32-bit) integer, when in fact it returns a (64-bit) pointer.  So you lose the top 32 bits of the pointer...

Answer (score 0):

this info, from http://web.cse.ohio-state.edu/~babic/Sem.shmem.new.pdf 
   needs to be taken into account:

important:
Semaphores and shared memories not explicitly removed stay in the system
after a process that created them terminates
and even when a user logs off.

Since UNIX
supports limited number of those resources, it is
important to make sure that all created
semaphores and shared memories are remo
ve before logging off.

The directory
/usr/class/cis660 include
s the script file
rsm
.dat that provides convenient way to remove all
semaphores and all shared memories at once.

An individual semaphore or shared memo
ry may be removed using UNIX command
ipcrm –s sem#
or
ipcrm –m mem#
, respectively, where sem# and mem# are obtained from UNIX command
ipcs
, which lists all semaphores and shared memories